# How is Grand Central Dispatch so fast? (For this Quicksort algorithm)

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, quicksort

In an effort to brush up on some multithreading/sorting fun, I decided to put together a Quicksort test (written in Objective-C) that uses Grand Central Dispatch to determine how much faster it is to leverage multicore machines.

[**main.m**](http://pastebin.com/UrJQr1cj)

[**QuickSort.m**](http://pastebin.com/g2DHwByj)

This is the output generated:

```
2011-11-27 13:10:55.595 Quicksort[1583:707] Took 4.731876 seconds to sort 1000000 elements with NO GCD
2011-11-27 13:10:55.670 Quicksort[1583:707] Took 0.070753 seconds to sort 1000000 elements WITH GCD
```

It's a fairly simple algorithm, using the **Simple version** mentioned on the Wikipedia page:

[Quicksort on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

I'm running this on an i7 machine, so would expect the performance increase to be on the order of 8x or so. Instead, the algorithm is **approximately 60-70x faster** when using Grand Central Dispatch.

Is the difference caused by a coding error on my part, or is there a technical advantage to using GCD that I'm just not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got an error somewhere in your code, I changed the lines

```
    NSLog(@"Took %f seconds to sort %lu elements WITH GCD", duration, NUM_ELEMENTS);
```

to

```
    NSLog(@"Took %f seconds to sort %lu elements WITH GCD", duration, [sorted count]);
```

now the output is

```
2011-11-27 18:40:28.020 qs[37855:707] Took 5.412689 seconds to sort 1000000 elements with NO GCD
2011-11-27 18:40:28.104 qs[37855:707] Took 0.082455 seconds to sort 1 elements WITH GCD
```

Still investigating why however...

Comment: Gave you a +1, the GCD version is definitely broken, but I'm also on the hunt as to why.

Comment: Looks like the semaphore waits aren't waiting properly, that's all I know so far.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's because they're initialized to 1 rather than 0, so the wait completes instantly

Comment: Ok, so you should be creating semaphores with `dispatch_semaphore_create(0)`, not `dispatch_semaphore_create(1)`. Now the algorithm gets a few iterations in, and hangs.... EDIT looks like Hasturkun beat me to that one!

Comment: I think the issue is the creation of the semaphore. I should be providing `0` as an argument, but I'm providing `1`, so the concatenation is not waiting for the less/greater arrays to be populated. (The semaphore is essentially useless.) When providing `0` however, it seems to hang indefinitely.

Comment: Could be that the global dispatch queue has a maximum number of jobs at once, so after a few recursions, it won't start new jobs until the current ones finish (and they don't finish because they're waiting for the jobs in the queue)

Comment: @JesseRusak That's my assumption as well - I had (mistakenly?) assumed that you could pile on as many tasks as you wanted, and GCD would appropriately sort them out, but it seems a limiting factor of some sort is still necessary.

Comment: You can use as many tasks as you want, but you can't have them all be incomplete until the very end. I think you need to restructure the algorithm to work even if only one job could run at a time.

Answer (score 1):

great algorithm.
basically split the work on smaller chunks (threads) and put the result together at the end.

as it is the semaphores do not wait.
changing it to dispatch_semaphore_create(0) does help with the wait, 
however in my SL machine GCD seems to recurse to deep, ie: i can end up with more than 500 worker threads. at which point the code simply hangs.

with a smaller subset of data it works great.

...

one more thing.
there seem to be another issue with memory, at least on my modified example.
solution, add a retain inside the dispatch_async()
and than a matching release after dispatch_semaphore_wait()

```
    // Create semaphore and sort the left side
    __block NSArray*  lessSorted = nil;
    dispatch_semaphore_t  lessSem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        lessSorted = [QuickSort sort:less useGCD:useGCD];

        [lessSorted retain];
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(lessSem);
    });

    // Create semaphore and sort the right side
    __block NSArray*  moreSorted = nil;
    dispatch_semaphore_t  moreSem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        moreSorted = [QuickSort sort:more useGCD:useGCD];

        [moreSorted retain];
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(moreSem);
    });

    // Wait for both sides to finish sorting
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(lessSem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(moreSem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    // Merge
    [concat addObjectsFromArray:lessSorted];
    [concat addObject:pivotObj];
    [concat addObjectsFromArray:moreSorted];

    dispatch_release(lessSem);            
    dispatch_release(moreSem);
    [lessSorted release];
    [less release];
    [moreSorted release];
    [more release];
```